# TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...) error in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-reanimated-v2

I'm detting this error whenever i try to use drawer navigation

```
    Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'NativeReanimated' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary.
Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

but this package is installed in my project
here is my package.json file

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
"react-native-bootsplash": "^3.1.5",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.0.0",
"react-native-recaptcha-v3": "^0.0.16",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

I had RNDocument Picker, the below worked for me:

Remove the package to start with: npm remove react-native-document-picker Install version 8.0.0

`$ npm install react-native-document-picker@8.0.0`

You can also try:

`$ npx react-native-asset react-native-document-picker`

If you get an error saying react-natiuve.config.js not found create a new file with that name in the root folder and add this:

```
module.Exports = { project: {ios: {},android: {},},assets: ['./src/assets/fonts/'], // path of your assert file};
```

then `npm start -- --reset-cache`